# Cannot install Debian Stretch on a single board computer Olimex Lime2

Tags: linux, debian, stretch, single-board

I'm trying to install Debian Stretch on a single board computer [Olimex Lime2](https://www.olimex.com/Products/OLinuXino/A20/A20-OLinuXIno-LIME2-4GB/open-source-hardware).

I tried the official images (both netinst and CD1) available here:
https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/armhf/iso-cd/

It didn't even boot.

Then, I used those instructions:
[https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/armhf/ch05s01.en.html](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/armhf/ch05s01.html.en)

I tried those ones, it started the kernel and got stuck, complaining "*** warning - bad CRC, using default environment", "could not initialize PHY ethernet@01c50000", "*** ERROR: serverip not set", "missing environment variable: pxeuuid", "missing environment variable: bootfile", "Config file not found" and "Unhandled DHCP Option in OFFER/ACK: 125":
http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/installer-armhf/current/images/u-boot/A20-OLinuXino-Lime2/

http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/installer-armhf/current/images/hd-media/SD-card-images/

http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/installer-armhf/current/images/netboot/SD-card-images/

Olimex provides a working image of Debian Jessie but the kernel is too old (3.4).

I wonder whether there is something wrong in the official images provided by Debian. Moreover, my problem with "bootfile" looks like this one:
https://github.com/armbian/build/issues/319

I'm currently running out of options. What can I do to install Debian Stretch on this machine? I already tried to migrate from Debian Jessie to Debian Stretch by using the image provided by Olimex but it broke the X server (not very important) and as the kernel was still too old, I had tons of troubles with systemd. By the way, I'd prefer using an official image provided by the Debian community.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself on the LIME2, but, depending on the purpose of your board, a simple option is to install [FreedomBox](https://freedombox.org/). They provide an LIME2-ready image that you can download [here](https://wiki.debian.org/FreedomBox/Hardware/A20-OLinuXino-Lime2). FreedomBox it is a Debian Pure Blend (based on Stretch), so you can remove any FreedomBox-specific packages to have a more "vanilla" Debian instead.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try very soon, I'll buy another SD card.

Answer (score 0):

»Could not initialize PHY ethernet@01c50000« on sunxi-boards is a feature since major release 2017.05 (i got to know it @ u-boot-sunxi-custodian-next-linksprite_pcduino-20170404T124211).

Use 2017.01, test a complete image, or extract only the u-boot to your sd-card, dhcp & tftp are friends ;-) Look here 
https://dl.armbian.com/lime2/archive/

---

Older u-boot only:
http://dl.linux-sunxi.org/nightly/u-boot-sunxi/u-boot-sunxi-custodian-next/u-boot-sunxi-custodian-next-20160829T174209-aa8e17b/u-boot-sunxi-custodian-next-a20-olinuxino-lime2.tar.xz

Comment: Would you mind clarifying on this answer and giving some direction or guidance in addition to what you already provided?

Comment: Do you mean that there is a regression in the major release? The problem is that I want to use Debian Stretch whereas the release of 2017.01 is Debian Jessie :s